# Routing confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In my routes I have

```
get '/about', to: 'pages#about'

resources :reckoners do
  resources :shift_requirements, shallow: true
end
```

And in  layouts/_footer.html.erb, which is called from application.html.erb, I have

```
<li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
```

Which works fine, unless I'm in the /reckoners/index.html.erb view, in which case I get the following error -

Couldn't find Reckoner with `'id'=about`

Looking at the params on the page, 'about' is being passed as the id, and the server log confirms that a query is being run for a reckoner object with that id. So I kind of understand why it's going wrong, but I'd like to understand why.

I have pages_controller.rb, which contains

```
def about
end
```

Comment: Can you post the full output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Can you also post your reckoners controller here

Comment: Hi - having looked at this again today, it appears now to be working, without any code changes. I'm going to leave it for a day, then if it's still gone I should delete the q? Sorry I've wasted everyone's time, was not my intention :(